# Searching large text files inside folder for specific text with php

Tags: php, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have request from client to add feature in app that will be like search engine for text files from specific folder. For example inside folder x are 20 doc, docx, txt files and i need to open every one of them and search file for inputed text. I thought to do it with plane php, because app is in vanilla php, but i am afraid that that feature will kill the server. Is there any quicker (execution time in php) and lighter way to do that? Can elasticsearch do something like this?

Comment: How many docs do you have ? tens or thousands or millions ?

Comment: It is not specified. But knowing the client it would be thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look at [Network drives connector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/network-drives.html).
Also you can try [fscrawler](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).